# cmake - multiple platform - Check for QNX

Tags: cmake, qnx

I have a cmake file, that will set some environment variables based on the  platform. Ex: UNIX, WINDOWS,

```
if(WIN32)
.....
endif(WIN32)


if(UNIX)
...
endif(UNIX)
```

Now I try cross-compiling

> QNX platform

in a

> Linux machine

with below settings:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(arch gcc_ntox86v7le)
set(SUBARCH x86)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER qcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER QCC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})
```

My problem is that when the above code is added to a CMAKE file, always QNX cross compilation will take place.

I am try to add some if(condition), so that the above setting apply only for QNX cross-compiling. But I cannot find any.

I tried with

```
if(UNIX)
....
elseif
     set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
     set(arch gcc_ntox86v7le)
endif()
```

But this always assumes it to be UNIX.

Comment: Usually cross-compiling uses **toolchain file**, which contains all settings you show. Toolchain file is passed to CMake with *CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE* command-line option. See more about toolchains in CMake [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I believe it will help... thanks